# Ruby on Rails application not regenerating stylesheets on deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, passenger, sass

I have a Ruby on Rails application that is not generating stylesheets properly. Sometimes SASS doesn't compile the SCSS into CSS and sometimes they concatenated CSS are not generated. I basically get an error writing the files, like this:

```
Error Message:
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /var/www/app/releases/20101004114929/public/stylesheets/cached_tutor24_tutor24-dot-ch-dot-simplificator-dot-com.css

Where:
pages#show
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb, line 673

Backtrace Summary:
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:673:in `initialize'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:673:in `open'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:673:in `write_asset_file_contents'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:433:in `stylesheet_link_tag'
[PROJECT_ROOT]/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:28:in `robust_stylesheet_link_tag'
[PROJECT_ROOT]/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:28:in `_run_haml_app47views47layouts47application46html46haml'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `send'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render_without_trace_View_path_r_2_Rendering'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render_without_trace_View_path_r_2_Rendering'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/newrelic_rpm-2.13.1/lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:319:in `render'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/newrelic_rpm-2.13.1/lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:141:in `trace_execution_scoped'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/newrelic_rpm-2.13.1/lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:314:in `render'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_view/base.rb:265:in `render_without_haml'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/haml-3.0.18/rails/./lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:13:in `render'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_view/base.rb:352:in `_render_with_layout'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_view/base.rb:262:in `render_without_haml'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/haml-3.0.18/rails/./lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:13:in `render'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1250:in `render_for_file'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/base.rb:936:in `render_without_benchmark'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:51:in `render'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1326:in `default_render'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1332:in `perform_action_without_filters'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_without_benchmark'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_without_flash'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in `perform_action_without_newrelic_trace'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/newrelic_rpm-2.13.1/lib/new_relic/control/./agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:254:in `perform_action'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/newrelic_rpm-2.13.1/lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:141:in `trace_execution_scoped'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/newrelic_rpm-2.13.1/lib/new_relic/control/./agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:247:in `perform_action'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `send'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process_without_filters'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:438:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/haml-3.0.18/rails/./lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:41:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/haml-3.0.18/rails/./lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:41:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/session/abstract_store.rb:177:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-2.3.9/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-2.3.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-2.3.9/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-2.3.9/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-2.3.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:92:in `process_request'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:207:in `main_loop'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:441:in `start_request_handler'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:381:in `handle_spawn_application'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:252:in `safe_fork'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:377:in `handle_spawn_application'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `__send__'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `main_loop'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:196:in `start_synchronously'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:163:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:222:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `spawn_rails_application'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:126:in `lookup_or_add'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:247:in `spawn_rails_application'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:80:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `spawn_rails_application'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:145:in `spawn_application'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:278:in `handle_spawn_application'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `__send__'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `main_loop'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.15/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:196:in `start_synchronously'
```

The whole /var/www/app is set to belong to www-data:www-data with permissions ug+rwX, a couple of times at deploy time.

Even after deploying I can go and check the permissions and they are fine:

```
# ls -la current/public/stylesheets/
total 92
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data  4096 Oct  4 14:11 ./
drwxrwxr-x 6 www-data www-data  4096 Oct  4 13:49 ../
```

and it still fails to create (or read the files).

Any ideas what might be going on?

Answer (score 1):

1. Does webserver really run as www-data user?
2. Aren't there some FS errors? (dmesg)
3. Does 'current' symlink point to the same directory under 'releases' that is shown in trace?
4. What happens if you change permissions on current/public/stylesheets to 777?

Comment: 1: yes, it does; I've checked just in case. I'll work on 2, 3 and 4 tomorrow when I'm back at the office. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: 2: there are no file system errors. 3: Yes, it is the same directory. 4: I've added that to our deploy process, and it started work, I removed it, and it continued work... so not sure.

Answer (score 1):

[Your app is probably *not* running as www-data.](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#user_switching)

Comment: Well, it should be running as www-data as that's the owner of config/environment.rb. For a short period of time the owner is root and indeed passenger is running as root although the documentation say it'll never run as root.

Comment: Phusion Passenger can run some internal helper processes as root but the application itself, e.g. all the "Rails: ..." and "Rack: ..." processes are never run as root. What are they running as according to ps?